# How to get Javascript input values in a dynamic HTML table

Tags: javascript, html

I need to collect all parameters values dynamically taking into consideration that I am using clone in in my javascript function. 
Can you give me an example for 3 times cloning !!
Here is the HTML:

```
<div  style="clear:both; float:left;margin-top:10px;border:1px solid #DDDDDD;background-color:#F0F0F0 ;padding:10px;width:1050px;">
<span style="color:blue;">Paiement</span>
<table id="tablePaiement" border="3">
    <tr id="row_1">
    <td></td>
    <td>                
    <table style="margin-top: 5px;">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                R&eacute;f Paiement
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                Date note
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                Date d&eacute;cision
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                Nature frais
            </td>   
        </tr>
        <tr id="row_data">
            <td>
                <form:input path="refPaiements" readonly="true" cssStyle="color:#C0C0C0;width:45px;"/>
            </td>                           
            <td>
                <input onchange="checkDateNoteDateDecision(this);" id="dateNote" name="dateNote" style="width:68px;" value='<fmt:formatDate value="${addDemandePaiementPaiementsRejetsCommand.dateNote}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>'/>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    calendar.set("dateNote");
                </script>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input onchange="checkDateNoteDateDecision(this);" id="dateDeLaDecision" name="dateDeLaDecision" style="width:68px;" value='<fmt:formatDate value="${addDemandePaiementPaiementsRejetsCommand.dateDeLaDecision}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>'/>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    calendar.set("dateDeLaDecision");
                </script>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:select path="type" items="${addDemandePaiementPaiementsRejetsCommand.types}" onchange="updateMontantPaie();"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>            
</div>
```

and this is the clone in javascript function that I am using with it:

```
function cloneRow() {
    var row = document.getElementById("row_1"); // find row to copy
    var table = document.getElementById("tablePaiement"); // find table to append to
    var previousRows = table.rows.length; //get number of lines
    var nextRow = previousRows + 1;
    if (nextRow > 15) {
        alert("un formulaire de paiement ne peut pas contenir plus de 15 paiements");
        return;
    }
    var clone = row.cloneNode(true); // clome
    clone.id = "row_" + nextRow; // change id or other attributes/contents
    table.appendChild(clone); // add new row to end of table        
}
```

Comment: Just use `getElementsByTagName`.

Comment: i did use it but it only give you an output value of a cell example:<td>value</td> but not the value when it is in a <input value="x"> i can not reach the "x"

Comment: No you didn't use getElementsByTagName. It doesn't give output value, it give list of elements having the given tag name.

Comment: thx @ShadowWizard i did find a way to do it using ur advice but still stuck cause i need to change the id of this `<tr id="row_data">` after cloning can u help please

Comment: thx i found it all i have to do was `clone.getElementsByTagName("tr")[1].id="newRow";`